# Plone: python script index_html related to a non folder object

Tags: python, plone, zope, plone-4.x

I've created a folder in a plone site (4.3.x) and I know it's possible define a python script (default method) **index_html** that runs on its request:

> [plone site]/[folder] --> request --> run index_html default method

The question now: Is there any resource to do the same on another object request in this folder? Something like this:

> [plone site]/[folder]/[page] --> request --> run page_html default method

If yes, how could I implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the Python Script as default view of the content.

Go to `/folder/page/manage_propertiesForm` and set a `layout` string property with value `page_html`.

**Please note**: this is the old way of doing stuff on Plone. It won't work on Dexterity based contents and Plone 5.
Please switch to modern approach using [Zope 3 browser views](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/views/browserviews.html).

Comment: Important issue about new plone versions. Thanks @keul.